# Casting ActiveModel attribute on return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, type-conversion, activemodel

In my Rails 3.1.1 project I have an ActiveModel that talks to API (ripped from Paul Dix's book, shortened for readability):

```
class Job
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON

  ATTRIBUTES = [ :id,
                 :title,
                 :description,
                 :company_id ]

  attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES

  validates_presence_of     :title, :description
  validates_numericality_of :company_id, :id

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    self.attributes = attributes
  end

  def attributes
    ATTRIBUTES.inject(
      ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new
      ) do |result, key|

      result[key] = read_attribute_for_validation(key)
      result
      end
  end

  def attributes=(attrs)
     attrs.each_pair {|k, v| send("#{k}=", v)}
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    send(key)
  end

  # More method definitions...
end
```

I instantiate `@job` in my controller, `new` action (`company_id` is a segnment key in the route: `/companies/:company_id/jobs/new`) like this:

```
@job = Job.new(company_id: params[:company_id])
```

Then, using CanCan, I check user's permissions to create to create a job. Basically, CanCan checks if current_user's `company_id` attribute matches job's `company_id`. This check fails because `@job.company_id` is returned as String.

Certainly, I can use params[:company_id].to_i while instantiating the object, but this seems like a workaround that I would have to repeat later.

**Question:**  is there a way to make my Job ActiveModel more "type-aware" and make it return int for `@job.company_id` call?

I googled around, checked `activemodel` source code, but doesn't seem to find an answer. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update**
I was thinking more of something like `schema` block for ActiveModel, just like the one in ActiveResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attr_accessor *ATTRIBUTES
```

create a method like this:

```
def company_id
  @company_id
end
```

You can just override that with

```
def company_id
  @company_id.to_i
end
```

Comment: I was thinking about it, but this would mean that I would have to do the same thing for all of the int attributes in the model. It is definitely more elegant than using `.to_i` in the controller. If I would not get a better response, yours will be accepted. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question....

mosch's answer suggested to override the getter for `company_id` in my ActiveModel. However, I would have to repeat this for all of `_id` attributes in the model. Therefore, I decided to cast all of the '_id' attributes to integers while initializing the object. As follows:

```
def attributes=(attrs)
    attrs.each_pair do |k, v|
      if "#{k}".include? "_id"
        send("#{k}=", v.to_i)
      else
        send("#{k}=", v)
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your Company `has_many => :jobs`?  If so, you could try

```
def new
  @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
  @job = @company.jobs.new
end
```

Comment: Both Company and Job are ActiveModels, therefore, traditional `has_many` and `belongs_to` don't work here...